# Refresh Multiselect after removing selected attribute via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When removing the "selected" attribute from options in a multiselect using .removeAttr("selected"), the options are not immediately redrawn in Chrome as being unselected.  Monitoring the DOM using Chrome Developer Tools shows that the selected attribute is removed from the DOM, but the options still appear to be selected until another item on the page is given focus.

Is there a way to get the options to redraw programmatically?  I've triggering "change" and some other events, but nothing seems to work besides have the user hover or click in an appropriate place.  It seems as if the browser forgets to redraw the elements until something else grabs its attention.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () {
    $("#x option").attr("selected", "selected");
});
$("#deselectAll").click(function () {
    $("#x option").removeAttr("selected");
});
```

And markup:

```
<a id="selectAll" href="javascript:void(0)">Select All</a>
<a id="deselectAll" href="javascript:void(0)">Deselect All</a>

<select multiple="multiple" size="5" style="height: 6em;" name="x" id="x">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
 </select>
```

This is in jQuery 1.7.1 and Chrome 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `focus` on it and immediately call `blur` it works. Try this.

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () {
    $("#x option").attr("selected", "selected");
});
$("#deselectAll").click(function () {
    $("#x").find("option")
    .removeAttr("selected")
    .end().focus().blur();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cQmug/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, this does in fact work.  I would still love to understand why it is necessary to cause the elements to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the width of the element like this:

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () {
    $("#x option").attr("selected", "selected");
});
$("#deselectAll").click(function () {
    $("#x option").removeAttr("selected").width($("#x option").width());
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rVvvc/)